# Unable to cast COM object of type System.__ComObject to IRibbonUI. IID 00c03a7-0000-0000-c000-000000000046 TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED 0x8002801d

Tags: microsoft-excel, skype-for-business, invantive-control

After applying Microsoft .NET patches or upgrade and then subsequent downgrade of Microsoft Office, I am getting an error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type System.__ComObject to IRibbonUI. IID 00c03a7-0000-0000-c000-000000000046 Library not registered TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED 0x8002801d
```

in an error window of Invantive Control when starting Microsoft Excel 2010.

A similar error occurs when installing Skype for Business with Office 2010:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to occur only when Office 2010 is involved; the problem has never been seen on Office 2013 or 2016.

It seems that Microsoft installers replace registrations, but don't cover all components especially with a downgrade back.

The recommended steps are:

- Make sure you have a tested backup of the device and registry so you can return to the original situation.
- Re-install the correct version of Visual Studio Tools for Office, such as from [Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/download/details.aspx?id=48217).
- Re-install Invantive Control from [Invantive Control site](https://download.invantive.com).
- Check whether the problem is resolved. If not, things get more tricky:
- Take the GUID from the eror message ({000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}).
- Open registry editor in elevated mode.
- Find the GUID {000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.
- Go to the TypeLib node.
- Copy the GUID from there ({2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}).
- Find {2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}.
- It lists multiple version numbers.
- Make sure you have a tested backup of the registry.
- Remove the 2.8 version number, keeping the 2.5 version.
- Restart Excel.
- When this doesn't help, the most easy route is to re-install Windows or test with Excel 2013 or 2016.